# Why after suspend only sometimes not detect USB, or deactivates driver (and how to fix)? monitors, Displaylink, Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, multi-monitor, dock, displaylink

Two monitors sometimes wake up from suspend, and other times they do not [e.g.](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=64206&highlight=suspend). *Specifically*, entering suspend and hitting the keyboard seems to wake up the monitors the first time. But clicking suspend the second time the monitors remain black. As a result USB devices connecting the monitors to the laptop with [Displaylink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742923/debian-recognizes-usb-c-docking-station-but-monitors-do-not-work/742935#742935) cannot be found, and the Displaylink driver is deactivated.
Only reboot works. Other usb connected devices to the dock work, such as keyboard and mouse. The issue seems independent of the [lid position](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510244/hdmi-monitors-not-correctly-detected-after-suspend-if-laptop-lid-closed) and does not occur ['intermittently'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622798/how-to-avoid-displaylink-dock-monitors-disconnecting-intermittently/728557#728557).

How  to troubleshoot? Is the issue due to DisplayLink, suspend, or something else?

The following did *not* work:

- [turn off USB autosuspend](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/311#issuecomment-350568606) and [blacklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device) in `tlp` or TLP UI.
- [`thunderbolt-tools`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747205/is-it-possible-to-reactivate-not-reload-a-driver-from-running-kernel?noredirect=1#comment1421749_747205), `tbtadm approve-all` and checking with `lspci devices`.
- Unplugging hdmi or usb-c of the dock.

I would not know what I would be doing:

- [remove](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=64193&highlight=suspend) `/etc/pm/sleep.d/displaylink.sh`.
- [udev rules](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=64314&highlight=suspend)
- [blacklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device)
- [powertop](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?326816-Issues-with-USB-hub-randomly-disconnecting-some-devices&p=1851649#post1851649)

Some possible involved files

```bash
/etc/tlp.conf 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup

/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/displaylink.sh
/usr/lib/systemd/system/displaylink-driver.service
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-displaylink.rules
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_displaylink
/opt/displaylink/suspend.sh
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_displaylink
```

***log**: suspend causes evdi to be disconnected/closed?*

```
$ sudo dmesg -w | grep Display

[    3.306247] usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[    7.395781] evdi: [I] (card1) Opened by Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[    7.397744] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[    7.399740] evdi: [I] (card2) Opened by Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[    7.401344] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[    9.889337] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[    9.912344] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[ 1849.616093] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[ 1849.616521] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[ 7301.667983] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[ 7301.668399] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11442.370372] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11442.370503] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.506775] evdi: [I] (card1) Disconnected from Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.534477] evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.536880] evdi: [I] (card2) Disconnected from Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.542512] evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)

# a little more dmseg output
[11293.477299] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: off
[11293.477327] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
[11293.479051] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: off
[11293.479737] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
[11302.597210] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[11302.613795] Filesystems sync: 0.016 seconds
[11302.614152] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
[11302.614496] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[11302.614516] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[11302.615831] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
[11302.615962] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
[11302.619720] OOM killer disabled.
[11302.619723] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[11302.621413] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[11302.892991] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[11302.930826] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[11438.215551] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[11438.233739] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11438.233740] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11439.737330] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11441.218576] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11441.537943] usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[11441.699720] OOM killer enabled.
[11441.699723] Restarting tasks ... 
[11441.699875] pci_bus 0000:08: Allocating resources
[11441.699914] pci_bus 0000:3c: Allocating resources
[11441.713490] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[11441.714617] done.
[11441.778266] PM: suspend exit
[11441.943765] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
[11441.943785] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying mode changed: 2560x1440@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
[11441.943786] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
[11441.953580] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: on
[11441.953595] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1080@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
[11441.953596] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: on
[11441.957136] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4720]
[11441.987991] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1264..], y [1132..]
[11442.370370] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect:883 (card1) Double connect - replacing 00000000249f7991 with 00000000249f7991
[11442.370372] evdi: [I] (card1) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11442.370374] evdi: [I] (card1) Connector state: connected
[11442.370502] evdi: [W] evdi_painter_connect:883 (card2) Double connect - replacing 00000000d81e37fa with 00000000d81e37fa
[11442.370503] evdi: [I] (card2) Connected with Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11442.370504] evdi: [I] (card2) Connector state: connected
[11445.432016] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying mode changed: 2560x1440@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
[11445.432022] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
[11445.444692] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying mode changed: 1920x1080@60; bpp 32; pixel format XR24 little-endian (0x34325258)
[11445.444698] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: on
[11495.853579] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Down
[11495.863841] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: off
[11495.863875] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
[11495.865487] evdi: [I] (card2) Notifying display power state: off
[11495.868225] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
[11498.374912] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[11498.387093] Filesystems sync: 0.012 seconds
[11498.387319] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
[11498.387679] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[11498.387682] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[11498.388599] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
[11498.388662] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
[11498.392991] OOM killer disabled.
[11498.392994] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[11498.394918] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[11498.466114] hub 4-1:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[11498.473177] usb 4-1.4: Port disable: can't disable remote wake
[11498.481987] usb 4-1-port4: cannot disable (err = -71)
[11498.596552] usb 4-1-port4: device 4-1.4 not suspended yet
[11498.641355] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[11503.725305] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[11503.725312] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: USBSTS: 0x00000000
[11503.725321] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[11503.725344] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[11503.749658] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[11549.036097] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[11549.054131] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11549.054135] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11550.541723] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11552.003809] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[11552.314323] usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[11552.487970] OOM killer enabled.
[11552.487973] Restarting tasks ... 
[11552.488140] pci_bus 0000:08: Allocating resources
[11552.488177] pci_bus 0000:3c: Allocating resources
[11552.488237] usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[11552.491498] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[11552.495234] evdi: [I] Detached from parent device
[11552.495237] evdi: [I] Detached from parent device
[11552.495386] usb 4-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[11552.495433] cdc_ether 4-1.3:2.0 enx806d973a4123: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:3c:00.0-1.3, CDC Ethernet Device
[11552.496390] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[11552.501152] done.
[11552.506775] evdi: [I] (card1) Disconnected from Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.506780] evdi: [I] (card1) Removing i2c adapter bus number 8
[11552.534477] evdi: [I] (card1) Closed by Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.536880] evdi: [I] (card2) Disconnected from Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.536882] evdi: [I] (card2) Removing i2c adapter bus number 9
[11552.538087] usb 4-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[11552.542512] evdi: [I] (card2) Closed by Task 1054 (DesktopManagerE) of process 919 (DisplayLinkMana)
[11552.567133] PM: suspend exit
[11552.738946] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4720]
[11552.769228] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1264..], y [1132..]
[11665.969996] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 6
[11666.277389] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[11666.427964] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=009a, bcdDevice= 1.64
[11666.427973] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[11666.427978] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: a9fd9886e55f
[11668.237192] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 13
[11669.029351] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[11669.179964] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=009a, bcdDevice= 1.64
[11669.179973] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[11669.179978] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: a9fd9886e55f
```

*displaylink-driver.service becomes inactive and usb device is not registered - after suspend*

```bash
$ sudo systemctl status displaylink-driver.service 
● displaylink-driver.service - DisplayLink Driver Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/displaylink-driver.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)

May 26 14:50:56 debija systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Driver Service...
May 26 14:50:56 debija systemd[1]: Started DisplayLink Driver Service.
May 26 18:03:21 debija systemd[1]: Stopping DisplayLink Driver Service...
May 26 18:03:22 debija systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Succeeded.
May 26 18:03:22 debija systemd[1]: Stopped DisplayLink Driver Service.
May 26 18:03:22 debija systemd[1]: displaylink-driver.service: Consumed 41min 25.761s CPU time.

$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc. Metallica MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b61e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1395:0025 Sennheiser Communications Headset [PC 8]
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 145f:020c Trust Trust Ergo Mouse
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04b4:5218 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. USB-Serial Bridge
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 17ef:1029 Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:1028 Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:5144 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


# missing usb devices (detected by $ lsusb before the issue)
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 17ef:a357 Lenovo USB3.1 Hub             
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 17ef:a359 Lenovo ThinkPad Lan
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 17e9:6015 DisplayLink ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 17ef:a356 Lenovo USB3.1 Hub
```

Comment: I know this problem from a Dell notebook with a single monitor connected over the dock, but running MS Windows. How do you tell it's not a hardware problem?

Comment: Thanks for the question:-) I do not. Do you suggest a change to the question or how it is framed? Please upvote it if you think there is a reason to ask.

Comment: (1) Did you compare the system logs between a successful wakeup and a failed one? If there is a software problem, there should be a difference visible. (2) Another idea to narrow the problem: What about other peripherals on the dock? Do they work correctly?

Comment: @Philippos I [attached](https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?p=95399) the syslog as part of the DisplayLink Support Tool to the forum. The syslog is too long to be pasted in my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access that without having an account there.

Comment: @Philippos updated with logs showing a bit more what is going on. Hope for your commentary.