# Why do DisplayLink monitors stop working after suspend in 6.x kernel?

Tags: kernel, multi-monitor, dock, displaylink

## Symptoms

2 out of 4 monitors don't light up after suspend. This is a similar problem as [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746739/why-after-suspend-only-sometimes-not-detect-usb-or-deactivates-driver-and-how) but not quite the same.

## Hardware

- Dell XPS 9320 plus (i7-1280P)
- [UD22 Dock](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000202555/only-two-monitors-display-on-dell-universal-dock-ud22)
- 4 monitors

## OS

- LinuxMint 21.2 with kernel 5.19.0-50 (all is well except, 10-15% chance, 1 of the monitors doesn't revive after suspend and I just need to reboot)
- LinuxMint 21.2 with kernel 6.2.0-26 (where the problem occurs)

## Software

- DisplayLink driver 5.6.1, 5.7.0, 5.8.0 [Standalone Installer](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu)

## Other info

Unlike [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746739/why-after-suspend-only-sometimes-not-detect-usb-or-deactivates-driver-and-how), the service is always "loaded" and "active (running)" even when 2 monitors don't revive.

```
$ sudo systemctl status displaylink-driver.service 

        ● displaylink-driver.service - DisplayLink Driver Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/displaylink-driver.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-08-14 09:06:37 EDT; 1h 48min ago
    Process: 1240 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c modprobe evdi || (dkms install $(ls -t /usr/src | grep evdi | head -n1  | sed -e "s:-:/:") && modprobe evdi) (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   Main PID: 1243 (DisplayLinkMana)
      Tasks: 53 (limit: 37856)
     Memory: 103.3M
        CPU: 24min 30.305s
     CGroup: /system.slice/displaylink-driver.service
             └─1243 /opt/displaylink/DisplayLinkManager

Aug 14 09:06:37 xps-9320 systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Driver Service...
Aug 14 09:06:37 xps-9320 systemd[1]: Started DisplayLink Driver Service.
```

## What I tried:

1. Upgrade the DisplayLink driver to 5.7.0 then 5.8.0
2. Upgrade evdi to 1.13.1 then 1.14.1
3. Restart the service

Nothing worked. So far the most effective way is to logout/login, which is much faster than reboot. Somehow the DisplayLink driver [causes a long hanging (120 secs)](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2310685#p2310685) during startup/reboot.

## Updates

1. Oct 31, 2023 - problem solved after upgrading to kernel 6.2.0-36
2. Jan 17, 2024 - upgrading from Linux Mint 21.2 to 21.3 somehow stopped the service. I had to start the service manually. `$ sudo systemctl start displaylink-driver.service`

Comment: Please refrain from posting text as image.

Comment: I apologize. Corrected.

Comment: Problem solved in kernel `6.2.0-36` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯